# How to focus control in the tabItem in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have tabControl in the form. In one of the tabItems I have textbox(myTextBox). Let's call it tabItem1. When I write something into the this text box placed in the tabItem1 I want to focus textbox(searchTextBox) in the tabItem2. I placed this code in the KeyDown of the

```
        tabItem2.Focus();
        searchTextBox.Text = searchTextBoxTeropatik.Text;

        searchTextBox.Focus();
```

I wrote this small function for this purpose.
But there is a big problem.

1. I press the Key
2. tabItem2 gets the focus.

But searchTextBox does not get the focus.(My problem)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Call `UpdateLayout()` after focusing the second `TabItem` so the system gets the time to redraw the tab.

```
  tabItem2.Focus();
  UpdateLayout();
  searchTextBox.Focus();
```