# WPF Initial focus for each TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Okay, I know this title looks like it has answers all around SO, but none of the answers found here worked for me. So, here goes.

I have this layout:

```
<Window>
  <Grid>
    <DockPanel>
      <TabControl>
        <TabItem>
          <Page x:Name="p">
            <Grid x:Name="g2">
              <TabControl x:Name="tc">
                <TabItem x:Name="ti1">
                  <StackPanel x:Name="sp">
                    <C:TextBox x:Name="txt"/>
                  </StackPanel>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem x:Name="ti2">
                  <C:DataGrid x:Name="dg"/>
                </TabItem>
              </TabControl>
            </Grid>
          </Page>
        </TabItem>
      </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now, my goal is to put focus on `txt` `TextBox` when `ti1` `TabItem` gets selected and on `dg` `DataGrid` when `ti2` `TabItem` gets selected. Also, I would really love to set this in `XAML`.

Note: I can only use controls that are named here, so up until `Page` control.

What have I tried so far:

- setting `FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=txt}"` on all of the parent controls in the parent tree of the `txt` `Control` (up until `Page`).
- setting `FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` on the `txt` and `dg` controls.
- setting focus in code through `TabControl`'s `SelectionChanged` event:

  - if ( ti1.IsSelected )
    {
    tc.UpdateLayout();
    FocusManager.SetFocusedElement( sp, txt );
    }
  - and
  - if ( ti1.IsSelected )
    {
    tc.UpdateLayout();
    txt.Focus();
    }

`TextBox` and `DataGrid` controls are created like `UserControl`s, but are actually classes that inherit `TextBox` and `DataGrid`, like this:

```
<TextBox ... </TextBox>
```

and

```
public partial class TextBox : System.Windows.Controls.TextBox
```

As I said, `XAML` solution is desired, but I will also settle for a code one, if former is not possible.

Comment: Would be nice to see outcome of each attempt (aka what happens). Since you tried what is the most obvious, it would be nice to have [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to just copy and play.

Comment: @Sinatr I'll try later, when there is more time, but for now I can say that all solutions, except `SetFocusedElement` one, had no effect, whatsoever. But using `FocusManager` resulted in visible `Caret` within `TextBox`, but focus was not there, I haven't been able to type. And that worked only for the initial opening of the page, when I selected some other tab, and than went back to the first one, even the `Caret` wasn't visible.

Comment: @Adder, please do not substantially edit other people's answers to include additional information. In your specific case I would recommend that you up-vote the answer for being helpful (if you feel like it) and post your own answer with additional information and accept it. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Alex, if I do that, people will see that his answer is the accepted one and use it, only to find it is not working. Why would I want that? I want people to see how to solve the problem, but also give credit to Keyur PATEL for helping me.

Comment: @Alex, sorry, I've read 'up-vote' but it got translated in my head as 'accept it' :). Never mind, I will do what you said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, the Dispatcher part from **Keyur PATEL's** answer was the solution for me, although not the complete one. The answer for me was to update `TabControl` layout with the `Dispatcher` and than invoke the `Focus` `Dispatcher`. So, the complete answer for me was:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( (Action) (() => tc.UpdateLayout()) );
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( (Action) (() => txt.Focus() ) );
```

or you can use just `Invoke` instead, for the UI thread to wait for your `Action`.

And for the reason why I had to use a `Dispatcher`, it is because I used it to change the selected tab in the first place. That is my best guess, at least.

Comment: Ah, glad you got it in the end :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try something similar to your code-behind solution but with this variation:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tc" SelectionChanged="tc_selectionChanged">
```

and in code behind:

```
InitializeComponent();

//if you know which control to focus by default when page is first loaded
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { txt.Focus(); }));
```

and

```
private void tc_selectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ti1.IsSelected)
    {
        txt.Focus();
    }
    else if (ti2.IsSelected)
    {
        dg.Focus();
    }
}
```

I tried this exact setup on my own WPF application so I know it works.

Helpful links:

[WPF TabControl On SelectionChanged, set focus to a text field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3971538/6741868)

and

[How to focus control in the tabItem ın WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8267139/6741868) (although for me it worked without `UpdateLayout()`)

Comment: This is not working for me. The `Caret` is visible, but the focus is not on the `TextBox`. [image of the textbox](https://postimg.org/image/41j8drx9vv/)

Comment: @Adder Interesting, I had the exact same problem (frozen Caret is visible, but typing something shows that the focus isn't on the textbox) but I got it working with the line `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { txt.Focus(); }));`. Can you verify you're calling it right after `InitializeComponent();` in code behind?

Comment: Possibly try `FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(txt, txt)` instead of `txt.Focus()`

Answer (score 0):

Found solution using extension attribute

```
public static class TabItemExtention
{
    public static bool GetIsSelected(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsSelectedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsSelected(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "IsSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(TabItemExtention),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsSelectedPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnIsSelectedPropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var uie = (UIElement)d;
        var tabItem = uie as TabItem;
        if (tabItem != null)
            tabItem.IsSelected = (bool)e.NewValue;
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            uie.UpdateLayout();
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
ctrl:TabItemExtention.IsSelected="{Binding IsTabNewCustomsDelaySelected}"
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was an extension method. Something was keeping my element from getting focus, so waiting until the context is idle fixed this.

```
    public static class UIElementExtensions
    {
        public static void FocusOnIdle(this UIElement element)
        {
            var result = element.Focus();

            if (result == false)
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    element.Focus();
                }), Threading.DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
            }
        }
    }
```